# Swift array map without $0 (Higher-Order Functions )

Tags: arrays, swift, higher-order-functions

I have a function that generates a number with some conditions

```
func randomWithCondition() -> Int {
  ...
  return n
}
```

And later I will use this function to build an array with N length in another function

```
func a() -> [Int] {
  var arr = [Int]()
  for _ in 0..<length {
    arr.append(randomWithCondition())
  }
  return arr
}
```

I want to write those in one line, the best thing I can think of is

```
return (0..<N).map { _ in randomWithCondition() }
```

I have to add `_ in` because I didn't use `$0`, otherwise it won't compile.

Question: Is there a walk round to not write `_ in`? any other format would be fine as long as it's one line in the return statement.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would be careful with that mindset. It’s what drives Java programmers to say “And what is the problem with blowing up your classes with getters and settersceeally? I am sure you can spend your programming time on more important tasks.” The eternal dissatisfaction of customers is great at driving improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` transforms each element from its type to other so that the transformation requires the parameter in the closure. But for convenience you can omit this parameter by making extensions for `Range` and `ClosedRange`:

```swift
extension Range where Bound: Strideable, Bound.Stride: SignedInteger {
    public func map<T>(_ transform: () -> T)  -> [T] {
        map { _ in transform() }
    }
}

extension ClosedRange where Bound: Strideable, Bound.Stride: SignedInteger {
    public func map<T>(_ transform: () -> T)  -> [T] {
        map { _ in transform() }
    }
}

let range = (0..<10).map { arc4random() }
print(range)
// Outputs: [676946806, 482060909, 1553829324, 1660236508, 606395000, 268649066, 1438948568, 1995527535, 918698113, 505678702]

let closedRange = (0...9).map { arc4random() }
print(closedRange)
// Outputs: [20467139, 198204705, 1585520963, 2022302907, 2518334206, 3304761403, 3782378335, 3830286797, 2200585433, 2387902936]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some extra functions yourself.

For example, a `const` function (name is inspired by Haskell, but you can call it `withParameter` instead):

```
func const<T, U>(_ f: @escaping () -> U) -> ((T) -> U) {
    { _ in f() }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
return (0..<N).map(const(randomWithCondition))
```

I think you should also wrap this in a `generate` function:

```
func generate<T>(_ count: Int, generator: @escaping () -> T) -> [T] {
    (0..<count).map(const(generator))
}
```

Do note that you can also create lazy infinite sequences with [`sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence), rather than `map`ping a range.